Using a similar model to map with gorm, but gorm preload is wrong
First, I have the Post model, which has been migrated to database
type Post struct {
    ID              uuid.UUID           `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key"`
    UserId          uuid.UUID           `gorm:"type:uuid;not null"`
    User            User                `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    ParentId        *uuid.UUID          `gorm:"type:uuid;default:null"`
    ParentPost      *Post               `gorm:"foreignKey:ParentId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Content         string              `gorm:"type:text;not null"`
}

Next, I have a similar model, but with an additional field isLiked, this model is not migrated and is only used to map from Post model to
type PostWithLiked struct {
    ID              uuid.UUID           `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key"`
    UserId          uuid.UUID           `gorm:"type:uuid;not null"`
    User            User                `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    ParentId        *uuid.UUID          `gorm:"type:uuid;default:null"`
    ParentPost      *Post               `gorm:"foreignKey:ParentId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Content         string              `gorm:"type:text;not null"`
    IsLiked         bool
}

This is the function to execute the query
func (r *rPost) GetOne(
    ctx context.Context,
    id uuid.UUID,
    authenticatedUserId uuid.UUID,
) (*entities.PostWithLiked, error) {
    var postModel models.PostWithLiked

    if err := r.db.WithContext(ctx).
        Model(&models.Post{}).
        Select(`posts.*,
        EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM like_user_posts
           WHERE like_user_posts.post_id = posts.id AND like_user_posts.user_id = ?
        ) AS is_liked
        `, authenticatedUserId).
        Where("posts.id = ?", id).
        Preload("User").
        Preload("ParentPost.User").
        First(&postModel).
        Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return mapper.FromPostWithLikedModel(&postModel), nil
}

Here is the query result
[56.799ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."parent_id" = '354fd551-96f0-4899-a7d7-e38ef524636f' AND "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL

[56.020ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = '129f1a32-ad18-49f1-b989-b6cd4c243e30' AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL

[469.482ms] [rows:1] SELECT posts.*,
        EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM like_user_posts
           WHERE like_user_posts.post_id = posts.id AND like_user_posts.user_id = '7dfdf978-9706-4720-aa3f-382af4b14f70'
        ) AS is_liked
         FROM "posts" WHERE posts.id = '354fd551-96f0-4899-a7d7-e38ef524636f' AND "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "posts"."id" LIMIT 1

ParentPost preload is wrong, actually the parent_id of the post is 6d591d06-80ee-4cf3-9695-e1eb986d7885, but it puts the post id in as 354fd551-96f0-4899-a7d7-e38ef524636f to perform preload
when i do the mappingFirst(&models.Post) parent post is preloaded correctly, but when i use PostWithLiked model then preload parentPost uses id of original post instead of parent_id
but when is use First(&models.PostWithLiked), it is wrong, please help me.

The preload is not working correctly because it needs the base model, it relies on the relationships on the Model and will structure the queries based on those. It got confused when you use other struct like PostWithLiked.
This is working like intended:
type Post struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID  `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key"`
    UserId     uuid.UUID  `gorm:"type:uuid;not null"`
    User       User       `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    ParentId   *uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:null"`
    ParentPost *Post      `gorm:"foreignKey:ParentId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Content    string     `gorm:"type:text;not null"`
}

type PostWithLiked struct {
    Post
    IsLiked bool
}

func (r *rPost) GetOne(
    ctx context.Context,
    id uuid.UUID,
    authenticatedUserId uuid.UUID,
) (*PostWithLiked, error) {
    var (
        post      Post
        postModel PostWithLiked
        isLiked   bool
    )

    if err := r.db.WithContext(ctx).
        Model(&Post{}).
        Where("posts.id = ?", id).
        Preload("User").
        Preload("ParentPost.User").
        First(&post).
        Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := r.db.Raw(`
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM like_user_posts
            WHERE like_user_posts.post_id = ? AND like_user_posts.user_id = ?
        )`, post.ID, authenticatedUserId).Scan(&isLiked).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    postModel = PostWithLiked{
        Post:    post,
        IsLiked: isLiked,
    }

    return &postModel, nil
}

Here are the queries processed:
[1.092ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = '571ee693-ffab-48a5-b098-3b270693cbea'

[2.146ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = '68cec1d2-b8ab-4966-aabe-94ac82b00902'

[0.347ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = '571ee693-ffab-48a5-b098-3b270693cbea'

[3.708ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE posts.id = '5a7b9b46-17ab-4851-a94e-0ea92c639d1e' ORDER BY "posts"."id" LIMIT 1

[0.568ms] [rows:1] 
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM like_user_posts
            WHERE like_user_posts.post_id = '5a7b9b46-17ab-4851-a94e-0ea92c639d1e' AND like_user_posts.user_id = '571ee693-ffab-48a5-b098-3b270693cbea'
        )

